# how to import __future__ for keyword-only argument of python 3.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, variadic-functions

The following code in python2.6 throws syntax error

```
>>> def f(a,*args,c):
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    def f(a,*args,c):
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

but this syntax is valid in python3.0. I would like to know what should I import in my interpreter to make it work.
ie. `from import __future__ ????`

for importing `print function` of 3.0, I would do `from __future__ import print_function`

similarly this defination is invalid in 2.6

```
def f(a,*b,c=5,**kwargs):
```

while it is legal in 3.0

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This feature of the Python 3 compiler has *not* been backported to Python 2.x.

There is no magic `from __future__ import` switch to enable it, your only option is to upgrade to Python 3.x.

Your second function could instead be defined as:

```
def (a, *b, **kwargs):
   c = kwargs.pop('c', 5)
```

to be Python 2 compatible.

Comment: Or `c = kwargs.pop('c', 5)`.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon: much better, yes.

Answer (score 5):

The new syntax is discussed in [PEP 3102](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) and it's indeed not valid in Python 2.x.

However you can obtain the keyword arguments from `**kwargs` manually:

```
def f(a, *b, **kwargs):
    if 'c' in kwargs:
        pass
```

The other alternative is to upgrade to Python 3.x.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to emulate keyword-only-arguments is:

```
def f(a, *args, **kwds):
    b = kwds.get('b', 42) # 42 being the default for b
```

if you wan't to make sure that no unsolicited arguments are passed you can use `pop` instead:

```
def f(a, *args, **kwds):
    b = kwds.pop('b', 42)

    assert not kwds # after we've popped all keywords arguments kwds should be empty
```